# Почему в архитектуре x64 старшие биты адресного пространства знаково расширяются

Tags: память, ос, x86-64, процессор, x86

Современные процессоры с архитектурой x86 насколько я понимаю поддерживают 48 бит для адреса виртуальной памяти, но старшие биты с 48 по 64 знаково расширяются, зачем это нужно делать? Почему неиспользуемые биты нельзя было бы оставить нулями?

Comment: [Похоже это упрощает](https://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=13995) различение user/kernel space при программировании внутри ядра